# Where is the "pala-" in "palabra" from in Spanish?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, historia

"palabla" sounds like "para habla" (means "for speaking"). There are some similar words like "paraguas, parachoques", but it seems that "para-" here means "parar" (that is, "stop") but not "para". So, "pala-" in "palabla" is different from "para-" in "paragua".

I'd like to know wether "pala-" is a prefix in Spanish or not. If that's true, where is it from and what does it mean? Could you teach me?

Some useful links are [para- elemento compositivo](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/para-elemento-compositivo.1391614/), [wiki para-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/para-) and [wiki pala-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pala-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word *palabra* is a whole word by itself in Spanish, it is not a compound of smaller parts.

The word comes from Latin *parabŏla*, meaning *comparison* but came to mean *proverb, parable* in Vulgar Latin. Before that, the word came from Ancient Greek *παραβολή parabolḗ*. This, in turn, came from *παραβάλλω parabállo*, *to compare*, and finally from *παρά pará*, *next to* and *βάλλω bállo*, *to throw*.

Comment: It seems that "parar" in "comparar" and "para-" in "paragua" are both from "parar", the former one means "put" while the later one means "stop". Am I right?

Comment: @EdenHarder _comparar_ is not a compound word in Spanish either. It comes from Latin _comparāre_.

Comment: But it seems that "comparar" = "com-parar", which means "put together (to compare)". :)